# Trying to install eclipse Bytecode Outline plugin, missing dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to install this: http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html, but I get this error which makes zero sense to me.

I'm running eclipse Kepler Service Release 1, build id 20130919-0819.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Bytecode Outline 2.1.0 (de.loskutov.BytecodeOutline.feature.feature.group 2.1.0)
  Missing requirement: Bytecode Outline 2.1.0 (de.loskutov.BytecodeOutline.feature.feature.group 2.1.0) requires 'org.eclipse.help.appserver 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Eclipse 3.3 "org.eclipse.help.appserver" was removed. See: [eclipse:help-appserver](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/porting/4.2/incompatibilities.html#help-appserver)

```
Description: This bundle provided implementation of a Tomcat-based web server application for the Eclipse help system. This was replaced in Eclipse 3.3 with a Jetty-based application server. This bundle defines no API and has been unused in the Eclipse platform for many releases.
```

Comment: Yeah, OK. But how does that help? Does that mean we need to go back to Eclipse 3.3 to use OW2?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the [Eclipse ASM Bytecode Outline plugin](http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html) was not maintained for quite some time which results in all kind of compatibility problems. For newer versions of Eclipse I therefore recommend installing [this alternate version](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Eclipse marketplace to find a version for the current eclipse version.