# cannot install asm framework and bytecode outline plugin

Tags: eclipse, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to install a plugin **http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html** using `ObjectWeb Eclipse Update Site`.

I selected `ASM Framework` and `Bytecode outline` via `Install New Software`. But during installation I've got an error

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context
was:(profile=epp.package.jee,phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, 
operand=null --> [R]org.objectweb.asm 2.0.0, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]org.objectweb.asm 2.0.0.
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the [Eclipse ASM Bytecode Outline plugin](http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html) was not maintained for quite some time which results in all kind of compatibility problems. For newer versions of Eclipse I therefore recommend installing [this alternate version](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/index.html) instead.

Anyway, the specific problem presented in this question can potentially be solved by installing the `Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support` from [The Eclipse Project Updates site](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4). Look in the `Eclipse Tests, Examples, and Extras` category. But as said this is not recommended because you will most likely run into other problems like e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880063/trying-to-install-eclipse-bytecode-outline-plugin-missing-dependency).

References:

- https://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/issues/detail?id=47
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421979